# In MongoDB aggregation, how would I sum values from a list within a list, and then from 2 lists to 1 value?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given the following result from an existing aggregation pipeline, I'm stuck trying to sum the values in "ibytes" to get 1 value, then also to do the same with "obytes".   You'll notice the values are a list within a list, but I can't seem to get them out to add them (all within the agg framework).  Directions or things to try?

Once this is solved, how to add the 2 values together?  ($add in a $project?)

```
    {
        "ibytes" : [
            [
                NumberLong(590),
                NumberLong(5184)
            ]
        ],
        "obytes" : [
            [
                NumberLong(0),
                NumberLong(0)
            ]
        ],
        "ipAddress" : "10.202.5.37",
        "hour" : ISODate("2013-08-22T12:00:00Z"),
        "deviceId" : 363
    }
```

Comment: You'd be better off keeping a running total or restructuring your data. Trying this in the AF is going to be very messy (if possible at all). The fact that you have more than one array you want to unwind is a challenge (as you'll end up with duplicates when you unwind). Just try unwind, unwind in an aggregate call to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following 4 stages to your aggregation pipeline

1. Unwind on ibytes
2. Group - perform sum during this "ibytes":{$sum:"$ibytes"}
3. Unwind on obytes
4. Group - perform sum during this "obytes":{$sum:"$obytes"}